# Having trouble toggling one element at a time (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Creating a grocery app for school and I'm having trouble selecting one element to cross out. I have the code written so far, and it kinda works, but where you click on the "check" button, it crosses out all the elements on the page with the same class, instead of just the individual item the "check" button is below, and associated with. How to I target just the one grocery item to cross out at a time with the "click" button? Something in my jQuery is not right.

```js
function checkItem() {
  $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', event => {

    const targetItem = $('.shopping-item');

    const otherItems = $('.shopping-item-toggle').not(targetItem);


    otherItems.removeClass('shopping-item__checked');

    targetItem.toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
  });  
}

$(checkItem);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

[Image of clicking one check box, but it crossing everything off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOidI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `event.target` to get the clicked element then `closest` for finding the element parent `li` and `children` to find the element you want to manipulate

```
$(event.target).closest('li').children('.shopping-item');
```

```js
function checkItem() {
  $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', event => {

    const targetItem = $(event.target).closest('li').children('.shopping-item');

    const otherItems = $('.shopping-item-toggle').not(targetItem);

    otherItems.removeClass('shopping-item__checked');

    targetItem.toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
  });  
}

$(checkItem);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
          <span class="button-label">check</span>
        </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
          <span class="button-label">delete</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the current shopping item using a combination of`closest` and `prev`, you are now selecting all shopping items

```
function checkItem() {
    $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', event => {
      const targetItem = $(event.target).closest('.shopping-item-controls').prev('.shopping-item');
      const otherItems = $('.shopping-item').not(targetItem);
      otherItems.removeClass('shopping-item__checked');
      targetItem.toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
    });  
  }
```

```js
function checkItem() {
  $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', event => {
    const targetItem = $(event.target).closest('.shopping-item-controls').prev('.shopping-item');
    const otherItems = $('.shopping-item').not(targetItem);
    otherItems.removeClass('shopping-item__checked');
    targetItem.toggleClass('shopping-item__checked');
  });
}
$(function() {
checkItem();
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Shopping List</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```